# Loop with random numbers, except the middle one

Tags: php, loops, random

I need to generate a random images gallery. Except that the  middle one has to always be the same.

Let's say I have 40 images. I need to choose 16 random images from the 40. The 9th image should always be the same.

Any idea ?

Precision :

The "hard" part for me is to know what numbers were already used, which weren't

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're displaying 16 images. Aren't those representative of what's already used?! What makes that "hard"?

Comment: I need to know so I don't use them with my random generation

Comment: See my answer. `$array` contains the used numbers. `$unused` has the numbers which were not included during shuffling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution without iteration:

```
$array=$original; // $original represents your 40 images
$ninth=$array[8]; // save 9th element for use later
unset($array[8]); // exclude the 9th element
shuffle($array); // randomize sequence
$array=array_slice($array,0,16); // get 16 images
$array[8]=$ninth; // replace 9th element with saved element
$unused=array_diff($original,$array); // list of unused elements
```

Comment: Perfect, except switching $array[9]=$ninth to array_splice($array, 8, 0, $ninth); Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

So, write a function printRandomImage()

call it 8 times, then print non-random image, then call it 7 more times.

If you want to avoid duplicates in random images, you have to remove already chosed images from the list of your 40 images.

Answer (score 0):

Something along those lines should help you out:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=16; $i++) {
  if ($i==9) {
    // show static image
  } else {
    // generate random nr between 1 and 40
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had that part figured out, the problem is knowing which numbers were already used, and which weren't.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that in your question :-) See @stillstanding's answer, no need to duplicate that.